# HTML to AttributedString and back

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I have the HTML below that I need to display in a UITextView (with a font of my choosing, say AvenirNext). I also need to allow users to format the text and send it as HTML to the backend. How would I accomplish this, keeping the format consistent?

```html
<p><strong>This is some text in bold</strong></p>

<p><em>Some text in italic</em></p>

<p><u>Some text underlined</u></p>

<ul>
    <li>Bullett list item one</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>

<ol>
    <li>Numbered list 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ol>
```